# instead of using OpenShift Container Platform monitoring based on Prometheus to do monitoring of containers, can we use something from Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

Trying to determine if cAdvisor + Prometheus is the OTHER option for monitoring openshift containers. Or if there is another combo that I can use natively from Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

cAdvisor is essentially built into K8S deployments so it's as native as you can get really. If you want to use additional software there are other ways to collect data with agents, but cAdvisor is quite well understood and efficient for doing this type of data collection. Prometheus also scrapes other K8S APIs aside from cAdvisor.

Comment: so I understand this correctly in the sense, that I don't NEED to use cAdvisor correct? If the Openshift container platform built in prometheus monitoring tool does the job that that should be good enough?

Comment: You need to use something that Prometheus can scrape for metrics. Depending on what metrics you want to collect. cAdvisor is the most common way to get system level data from Docker (and hence Kubernetes workloads).